Prove that in a connected planar graph $G$ with $n \geq 6$ vertices, for any three vertices $u, v, w$, we have $d(u) + d(v) + d(w) \leq 2n + 2$.
Prove that in a connected planar graph $G$ with $n \geq 6$ vertices, for any three vertices $u, v, w$, we have $d(u) + d(v) + d(w) \leq 2n + 2$.
This question seems to make use of Euler's formula and the fact that $ 3f \leq 2e$, $e \leq 3v - 6$, $f \leq 2v - 4$. But I just don't have idea how to prove it.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

What is $d(u)$? Degree of vertex $u$?

Usually yes, d(u) refers to the degree of vertex $u$. I suspect that an induction proof will work here but there is likely to be a simpler proof. Thinking about it.

Have you considered using the fact that $d(u)+d(v)+d(w)=2e$ for any graph?

@RedFive Not for any graph, only for graphs with three vertices in them.

Yes. Fair point.
